# Symfony2 assets are not shown

Tags: php, symfony, assets

I'm working on Symfony2.
pq anyone knows my website takes no assets correctly?

I'm working on app.php with `$ kernel = new AppKernel ('prod', false);`
When I upload the site to the web server but I see the assets. I tried to do this:

```
assets: installl - symlink web
assets: install web
```

the install but still the same.

I have also tried to clear the cache and not working.

```
aradasymfony@ssh:~/www/pfc$ app/console assets:install web
Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle into web/bundles/framework
Installing assets for mio\mioBundle into web/bundles/miomio
Installing assets for FOS\JsRoutingBundle into web/bundles/fosjsrouting
Installing assets for Acme\DemoBundle into web/bundles/acmedemo
Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle into web/bundles/webprofiler
Installing assets for Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle into web/bundles/sensiodistribution
paradasymfony@ssh:~/www/pfc$ app/console --env=prod cache:clear
Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug true
```

web: http://paradasymfony.alwaysdata.net/pfc/web/login

thanks.

Comment: Your app displays assets correctly when I look at the provided link

Answer (score 0):

The most common problem after deployment is that your `app/cache` and `app/logs` folders don't have appropriate permissions. As a quick fix try changing them to `777` (or create if neither of them exists).

For proper permissions configuration read [this chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup) (permissions section).

If it does not help - you can either read logs in `app/logs` folder or in your web-server logs and tell us what is an error, or you can expose `app_dev.php` file to world and check exception given by it.

Comment: `paradasymfony@ssh:~/www$ chmod 777 -R pfc/
paradasymfony@ssh:~/www$ ls
copias  doc_pfc.tar.gz  pfc
paradasymfony@ssh:~/www$` no work.

Comment: Sorry, this comment tells me nothing :)

Comment: @faisbu and what about other tips? Any log info?